# add class when div is underneath another

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add a class to a div when it slides underneath another div.  See my simple timeslider example.  I want to add a class to the div that would bolden the font below the timeslider like the hover state replicating a Mac dock magnification hover effect.  Also would like to add a class to the two times on the top and bottom of the time under the red slider.

http://codepen.io/pixelchef/pen/Bpghm

```
<div class="times">
      <div class="datepast hour">
               - 9 am
            </div>
         <div class="datepast hour">
               - 10 am
            </div>
         <div class="datepast hour">
               - 11 am
            </div>
         <div class="datepast hour">
               - 12 am
            </div>
                <div class="datepast hour">
               - 1 pm
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, you want to know how to know when a div hovers another.
I made a little work-around witch might work for you.

JSFIDDLE: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/wujood/zyhm5gyj/5/)

I had a big issue with locating a `position: fixed` container and getting its position inside a scrollable div, BUT since its all about the looks i thought i will give you an answer that at least shows bold text in the middle of a container.

Please Note that the important part happens in `$("#Background").scroll()`, everything else is just for the looks.

HTML:

```
<div id="Background" class="bg">
    <div id="list"></div>
    <div id="boldarea"></div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
var list = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    list.push(i + "am"); 
}

var elements = ""; 
list.forEach(function (entry, index) {
    elements += "<div class=\"text\">" + entry + "</div>"; 
});
$("#list").html(elements);

//SCROLL EVENT 
$("#Background").scroll(function () {
    $("div .text").each(function (index, entry) {
        console.log($("#boldarea").offset().top);
        if ($(entry).position().top > (($("#boldarea").position().top/2) - 8) && 
            $(entry).position().top < (($("#boldarea").position().top/2) + 8) ) 
        {
            $(entry).css("font-weight", "bold");
        } 
        else 
        {
            $(entry).css("font-weight", "normal");
        };
    }); 
});
```

Instead of 
`$(entry).css("font-weight", "bold");` 
you could write 
`$(entry).addClass("myClass");` 
for more dynamical styling.

CSS:

```
#boldarea {
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%;
    height: 12px;
    width: 35%;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.bg {
    position:absolute;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    top:25%;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.text {
    position: relative;
    color: black;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```